# Embedding a boost-spirit grammar parsing into a struct into another grammar gives compilation errors

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi, boost-fusion

I'm using boost spirit to parse some text. For this I have two grammars. The first one parses a string into a struct, the second one, takes a grammar as template argument and uses it to parse a sequence of data. The second parser should be flexible enough to also handle other grammar return types. Since the original parser is too large to act as a minimal example, I have reduced the code as much as I can, leaving me with something that would not parse anything, but still results in the same compilation errors: ([Code on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af46910b7f95a448))

```cpp
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <vector>

namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;


struct Struct1
{
  float f;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Struct1,
    (float, f))

struct Struct2
{
  float f;
  int i;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Struct2,
    (float, f)
    (int, i))


template<typename Iterator,
         typename Result>
class ElementParser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Result(), ascii::space_type>
{
public:
  using ValueType = Result;
  
  ElementParser() : ElementParser::base_type(element) {}
  
private:
  qi::rule<Iterator, Result(), ascii::space_type> element;
};


template<typename Iterator,
         typename ElementParser,
         typename Element = typename ElementParser::ValueType>
class SP : public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<Element>(), ascii::space_type>
{
public:
  SP()
    : SP::base_type(sequence)
  {
    sequence %= simpleVector % ',';
    // The simpleVector hack is really needed because of some other parsing
    // stuff, that is going on, but has been left out here.
    simpleVector %= qi::repeat(1)[simple];
  }
  
private:
  using Rule = qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Element>(), ascii::space_type>;
  Rule sequence;
  Rule simpleVector;
  ElementParser simple;
};


void sequenceTest()
{
  using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
  
  SP<Iterator, qi::uint_parser<>, std::size_t> uintParser;                  // OK
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, float>> floatParser;                 // OK
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, std::vector<float>>> vectorParser;   // OK
  
// error: invalid static_cast from type 'const std::vector<Struct1, std::allocator<Struct1> >' to type 'element_type' {aka 'float'}
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, Struct1>> struct1Parser;
  
// error: no matching function for call to 'Struct2::Struct2(const std::vector<Struct2, std::allocator<Struct2> >&)'
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, Struct2>> struct2Parser;
}
```

As long, as I am using simple types or vectors as return types of the `ElementParser`, everything is working fine, but as soon as I'm parsing into a struct (which in itself is working fine), the sequence parser `SP` seems to try some stange assignments. Why do the struct versions result in compilation errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an even shorter example, demonstrating the same problem ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ca3bTd)):

```cpp
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

void test()
{
  using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
  
  // OK
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>(), ascii::space_type> vecI_src;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>(), ascii::space_type> vecI_dst = *vecI_src;
  
  // error: no matching function for call to 'std::tuple<int, float>::tuple(const std::vector<std::tuple<int, float> >&)'
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>(), ascii::space_type> vecT_src;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>(), ascii::space_type> vecT_dst = *vecT_src;
}
```

I think, the problem is, that vectors and tuples are handles quite similarly in the underlying `boost::fusion` library, so when it comes to flattening the vector, `boost::fusion` overshoots the goal and assignment fails. (Possibly by some kind of SFINAE mechanism.) Now, that flattening the vector does not work, the right-hand-side `tuple` parser's synthesized attribute is of type `vector<vector<tuple<int, float>>>`, as opposed to the expected `vector<tuple<int, float>>`.

Knowing this, the (not very pretty) solution I've found (for the original example) is to manually create assignment function overloads for both expected forms:

```cpp
  static
  void flattenAndAppend(std::vector<Element>& into,
                        std::vector<std::vector<Element>> const& vector)
  {
    for(auto const& subvector: vector)
    {
      into.insert(into.end(), subvector.begin(), subvector.end());
    }
  }
  
  static
  void flattenAndAppend(std::vector<Element>& into,
                        std::vector<Element> const& vector)
  {
    into.insert(into.end(), vector.begin(), vector.end());
  }
```

and call these in a semantic action via a `boost::phoenix` function:

```cpp
    ph::function append = [](auto& into,
                             auto const& a1)
    {
      flattenAndAppend(into, a1);
    };
    
    sequence = (simpleVector % ',')[append(qi::_val, ql::_1)];
```

Here is the whole working example ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/efKhfn)):

```cpp
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ql = qi::labels;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;


struct Struct1
{
  float f;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Struct1,
    (float, f))

struct Struct2
{
  float f;
  int i;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Struct2,
    (float, f)
    (int, i))


template<typename Iterator,
         typename Result>
class ElementParser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Result(), ascii::space_type>
{
public:
  using ValueType = Result;
  
  ElementParser() : ElementParser::base_type(element) {}
  
private:
  qi::rule<Iterator, Result(), ascii::space_type> element;
};


template<typename Iterator>
class Struct2Tuple : public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::tuple<float, int>(), ascii::space_type>
{
public:
  using ValueType = std::tuple<float, int>;
  
  Struct2Tuple() : Struct2Tuple::base_type(tupleElement)
  {
    ph::function convert = [](auto const& s,
                              auto& t)
    {
      t = std::make_tuple(s.f, s.i);
    };
    
    tupleElement = structElement[convert(ql::_1, qi::_val)];
  }
  
private:
  qi::rule<Iterator, ValueType(), ascii::space_type> tupleElement;
  ElementParser<Iterator, Struct2> structElement;
};


template<typename Iterator,
         typename ElementParser,
         typename Element = typename ElementParser::ValueType>
class SP : public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<Element>(), ascii::space_type>
{
private:
  static
  void flattenAndAppend(std::vector<Element>& into,
                        std::vector<std::vector<Element>> const& vector)
  {
    for(auto const& subvector: vector)
    {
      into.insert(into.end(), subvector.begin(), subvector.end());
    }
  }
  
  static
  void flattenAndAppend(std::vector<Element>& into,
                        std::vector<Element> const& vector)
  {
    into.insert(into.end(), vector.begin(), vector.end());
  }
  
public:
  SP()
    : SP::base_type(sequence)
  {
    ph::function append = [](auto& into,
                             auto const& a1)
    {
      flattenAndAppend(into, a1);
    };
    
    sequence = (simpleVector % ',')[append(qi::_val, ql::_1)];
    simpleVector = qi::repeat(1)[simple];
  }
  
private:
  using Rule = qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Element>(), ascii::space_type>;
  Rule sequence;
  Rule simpleVector;
  ElementParser simple;
};


void sequenceTest()
{
  using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
  
  SP<Iterator, qi::uint_parser<>, std::size_t> uintParser;                  // OK
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, float>> floatParser;                 // OK
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, std::vector<float>>> vectorParser;   // OK
  
  SP<Iterator, Struct2Tuple<Iterator>> struct2tupleParser;                  // OK.
  
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, std::tuple<float, float>>> tupleParser;   // now OK
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, Struct1>> struct1Parser;                  // now OK
  SP<Iterator, ElementParser<Iterator, Struct2>> struct2Parser;                  // now OK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're skirting the age-old single-element-sequence compatibility rules. Especially with Struct1 which is indeed adapted as a single-element sequence.

However, in your code I could easily make it work by removing the unnecessary `repeat(1)[]` contraption:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb116356f25311da)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Struct1 { float f; };
struct Struct2 { float f; int i; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Struct1, f)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Struct2, f, i)

template <typename Iterator, typename Result>
class ElementParser
    : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Result(), ascii::space_type> {
  public:
    using ValueType = Result;

    ElementParser() : ElementParser::base_type(element) {
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, Result(), ascii::space_type> element;
};

template <typename Iterator, typename ElementParser,
          typename Element = typename ElementParser::ValueType>
class SequenceParser
    : public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<Element>(), ascii::space_type> {
  public:
    SequenceParser() : SequenceParser::base_type(sequence) {
        sequence = simple % ',';
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Element>(), ascii::space_type> sequence;
    ElementParser simple;
};

void sequenceTest() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    SequenceParser<It, qi::uint_parser<>, std::size_t> uintParser;  // OK
    SequenceParser<It, ElementParser<It, float>> floatParser; // OK
    SequenceParser<It, ElementParser<It, std::vector<float>>>
        vectorParser; // OK

    SequenceParser<It, ElementParser<It, Struct1>> struct1Parser;
    SequenceParser<It, ElementParser<It, Struct2>> struct2Parser;
}

int main() {
    sequenceTest();
}
```

### BONUS: `JustParseIt` magic function

Note that it looks like you are, to an extent, religitigating the library design. Have a look at [`qi::auto_`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auto.html).

Add to that the ideas from here:

- [Using the auto_ expression in boost::spirit with std::vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132223/using-the-auto-expression-in-boostspirit-with-stdvectors/28138768#28138768)
- [`create_parser` trait](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/auto/create_parser.html)

For example by specializing the trait to make comma-separated sequence parsers:

```
template <typename... T>
struct create_parser<std::vector<T...>> : comma_separated_sequence {};

struct comma_separated_sequence {
    using type = decltype(qi::copy(qi::auto_ % ','));
    static type call() { return qi::copy(qi::auto_ % ','); }
};
```

Now you can implement a `JustParseIt` function that works with /the world/:

```
bool JustParseIt(std::string_view input, auto& val) {
    return qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), qi::auto_, qi::space, val);
}
```

You'll be surprised to see what it parses:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/49j7Kd)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace MyLib {
    struct Struct1 { float f; };
    struct Struct2 { float f; int i; };
    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyLib::Struct1, f)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyLib::Struct2, f, i)

namespace {
    struct comma_separated_sequence {
        using type = decltype(qi::copy(qi::auto_ % ','));
        static type call() { return qi::copy(qi::auto_ % ','); }
    };
}

namespace boost::spirit::traits {
    template <typename... T>
    struct create_parser<std::list<T...>> : comma_separated_sequence {};

    template <typename... T>
    struct create_parser<std::vector<T...>> : comma_separated_sequence {};
}

bool JustParseIt(std::string_view input, auto& val) {
#ifdef BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
    using It      = decltype(input.begin());
    using Skipper = qi::space_type;
    using Attr    = std::decay_t<decltype(val)>;
    static qi::rule<It, Attr(), Skipper> parser = qi::auto_;
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(parser);
    return qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser, qi::space, val);
#else
    return qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), qi::auto_, qi::space, val);
#endif
}

int main() {
    using namespace MyLib;
    std::cerr << std::boolalpha; // make debug easier to read

    float f;
    JustParseIt("3.1415", f);

    uint64_t u;
    JustParseIt("00897823", u);

    Struct1 s1;
    JustParseIt("3.1415", s1);

    Struct2 s2;
    JustParseIt("3.1415 00897823", s2);

    std::list<float> floats;;
    JustParseIt("1.2,3.4", floats);

    std::list<Struct1> list1;
    JustParseIt("1.2", list1);
    JustParseIt("1.2, -inf, 9e10, NaN", list1);

    std::vector<boost::variant<Struct2, bool> > variants;
    JustParseIt("true, 9e10 123, NaN 234, false, false", variants);

    std::vector<Struct2> vec2;
    JustParseIt("9e10 123, NaN 234", vec2);

    // this is pushing it - for lack of structurual syntax
    std::vector<std::tuple<bool, Struct1, std::vector<Struct2>>> insane;
    JustParseIt("true 3.14 1e1 1, 2e2 2, 3e3 3, false +inf 4e4 4", insane);

    fmt::print("float f: {}\n"
            "uint64_t u: {}\n"
            "std::list<float> floats: {}\n"
            "std::list<Struct1> list1: {}\n"
            "std::vector<Struct2> vec2: {}\n"
            "Struct1 s1: {}\n"
            "Struct2 s2: {}\n"
            "std::vector<boost::variant<Struct2, bool> > variants: {}\n"
            "std::vector<std::tuple<bool, Struct1, std::vector<Struct2>>> "
            "insane: {}\n",
            f, u, floats, list1, vec2, s1, s2, variants, insane);
}
```

Prints

```
float f: 3.1415
uint64_t u: 897823
std::list<float> floats: {1.2, 3.4}
std::list<Struct1> list1: {(1.2), (1.2), (-inf), (9e+10), (nan)}
std::vector<Struct2> vec2: {(9e+10 123), (nan 234)}
Struct1 s1: (3.1415)
Struct2 s2: (3.1415 897823)
std::vector<boost::variant<Struct2, bool> > variants: {1, (9e+10 123), (nan 234), 0, 0}
std::vector<std::tuple<bool, Struct1, std::vector<Struct2>>> insane: {(true, (3.14), {(10 1), (200 2), (3000 3)}), (false, (inf), {(40000 4)})}
```

> Note that you can [define `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG`](https://godbolt.org/z/49E3nE) to get parser debugging to stderr, like e.g.
>
> ```xml
> <parser>
>   <try>true, 9e10 123, NaN </try>
>   <success></success>
>   <attributes>[[true, [9e+10, 123], [nan, 234], false, false]]</attributes>
> </parser>
> ```

Comment: Hi @sehe, thanks for your answer. the `repeat(1)[]` unfortunately is necessary: This sequence parser includes a nested repetition parser and for this to work, the single element needs to be made compatible with “older” results, which are already vectors. That's why I've added this comment above the singleVector rule. This works fine in all other cases I have, but the struct is somehow killing it. Especially the `Struct2` case. I don't understand, why it wants to assign a whole vector to a single element.

Comment: The `JustParseIt` function looks interesting. Is it possible to use predefined grammars in the `create_parser` trait? I thought about rewriting the sequence grammar, to take the element parser as a template argument, which could then also be `qi::auto_`. But that would require to somehow pass the iterator type to the grammar, which as I see it cannot be done, using `create_parser`. Any hints?

Comment: Mmm. I think it's strictly more versatile to keep the parser expressions in the realm of Qi Domain proto expressions (that is, not binding to a static iterator type). If you need the attribute coercion/transformation capabilities of `qi::rule`, use [`qi::attr_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/attr_cast.html).

Comment: That said, if you don't mind the genericity/versatility _or_ just have a boat load of legacy rules already, you can of course just implement create_parser **assuming** a static iterator type (which will simply not compile if the iterator type doesn't match).

Comment: Here's a demo of that: [without `-DUSE_LEGACY_STRUCT2_PARSER`](https://godbolt.org/z/en5dKT) contrast with [using `-DUSE_LEGACY_STRUCT2_PARSER`](https://godbolt.org/z/vqqT3s). I made Struct2 legacy rule accept "[float; int]" input

Comment: Hmm, I tried using `qi::auto_` in the sequence grammar, but that ultimately lead to the same [compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/4jhncG). I guess, I will have to rewrite the whole thing, to not use the struct, or maybe I can input an abstraction layer, that converts the struct into something useable. Maybe you can include a short explanation or link to the single-element-sequence compatibility rules, and I will accept your answer. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. The whole point about using auto_/create_parser is to **not** use the `SP<>` thing. If you insist on it, then forget about the auto?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228922/discussion-between-sehe-and-wolfgang-lorenz).